# An app build does not appear in TestFlight

Tags: ios, archive, testflight

I don't remember this has happened to me before, but for some unknown reason my last app build does not appear in TestFlight. The archiving and upload went as usual with no problem. And if I try to make a new upload, it says there is already a build with this number (as expected).

Has anyone experienced the same issue and found a working solution?

Comment: check your plist. If your app misses location or camera usage description or any information like this than it does not appear on TestFlight though it got submitted successfully. This happened with me while working on an ionic app.

Comment: Same Build number you cant upload it. you have to change build number. OR you can submit uploaded build on testflight.

Comment: @Muhammad Nayab. This app does not use camera or location. Beside, several builds have been submitted before without any particular problem.

Comment: @Vishal Patel. I know I can't upload with the same build number. That was only a test because the build I had already uploaded was not showing up. But as I wrote, it did not work (as I expected).

Comment: if you have uploaded build now then its in processing.. its not show into testflight. when processing completed its automatically comes into testflight.

Comment: Well, but this usually takes five minutes. Here it is taking two hours. Something is wrong.

Comment: Actually I just got a mail, explaining what is wrong. Apple has changed the rules, tough I do not use location, I am appearently using some library that does. And for that, I need to adjust my info.plist.

Comment: @Michel this is what I was saying.

Comment: @Muhammad Nayab. You were right :)

Comment: i think you should answer your question so that  someone find it useful. :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Check email linked with apple account, you might have received email listing with issues apple found on your build which most of the times related to .plist file for any missing permission description. After removing issues do change the build Number as you cannot upload with the same build number as previous one.

Comment: Yes, this exactly what happened as alredy written in my comment above.

Answer (score 5):

Besides the reason mentioned by *Ali* there can be one more thing. Your application might be in processing for the time. Just go to:

Your application>TestFlight>Activity

Check if the application with the uploaded build version is there and status is in processing. It may take up to an hour or more before it comes to your testing tab.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but if you read my post you will see that this was exactly the issue. The buid was no there.

Comment: Well it was a while ago. So I don't exactly remember. But I think it just solved itself by waiting a bit.

Answer (score 2):

We encountered the same issue and here is our breakdown of steps.

Important note - phone connects to BT device

Our steps: Solution is under 4. and 6.

1. Archive the app and upload it over Xcode successfully

   1. Used automatic signing
   2. Everything went smoothly, and Xcode showed a successful upload
2. Build never shows up on TestFlight

   1. There are no emails about failed processing or any indication of what went wrong
3. Accidentally found that we’re missing Bluetooth privacy string in Info.plist
4. **Added `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`**, archived, and uploaded again

   1. Used automatic signing
   2. Everything went smoothly, and Xcode showed a successful upload
5. Received an email from AppStoreConnect that Info.plist is missing `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`

   1. This is the first email I received stating something is wrong. Only after adding `NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription`
6. **Added `NSBluetoothPeripheralUsageDescription`**, archived, and uploaded again

   1. Used automatic signing
   2. Everything went smoothly, and Xcode showed a successful upload
7. **Build visible on TestFlight within several minutes**
8. :party

The issue was that the app was crashing because it was missing the string. The app did not crash on our testing device because that string was once there and the system already asked the user for permission. The field was probably accidentaly deleted during development.

**To find similar issues, try to delete the app from your device and install it again to see if it runs.**

Answer (score 2):

Check your email which are configured with apple account.

so you can see the Emil like this below:

[image]

then I go to the info.plist file and put there below code:

```
    <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>my app using to access the photo from library.</string>
```

then try to archive with new build version, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix the problem by adding this key "App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption" in Info.plist

App Uses Non-Exempt Encryption = NO

Comment: I wonder why this is related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this issue before, tried all the fixes had not received any mail from apple about what the issue is, but finally fixed the issue after making changes in the info.plist file the issue was that description was missing in info.plist file, mostly it occurs because of that check the file again.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the error when I make a build and upload it to the app store it display successfully on Xcode. but the build was not appearing on the app store test flight. then I check my email where the app store team was indicating my issue clearly. in my case, my app name contains a white space on starting.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).